# Uniqueness of a Limit epsilon divided by 2?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, convergence-divergence

I have been reading about this theorem in a book called 'Calculus: Basic Concepts for High-schools', it is a very good book (so far) and I can highly recommend it.

Well the author goes on to prove that: 'A convergent sequence has only one limit', which is quite intuitive in  geometrical sense..

However in the beginning of his proof (which is a proof by contradiction) he goes on to state:

"Consider a convergent sequence with two limits a1 and a2 and select a value for epsilon < (absolute value of)a1-a2/2.

First of all why does epsilon have to be smaller than the value on the right of the inequality?

Where does the author derive this inequality from? Is it just some arbitray inequality?

Why does the distance between a1 and a2 have to be divided by 2?

Finally any other explanations/proofs for a more intuitive understanding of the uniqueness of a limit are welcome.

(Excuse me, for not using LATEX it is a thing I'm not yet familiar with..)

Comment: They derive the inequality and the required epsilons by working the problem backwards, but they present it in a forward manner as if by magic.

Comment: Can you be more specific ? ;)

Comment: The inequality $\epsilon < |a_1 - a_2| / 2$ is ensuring that the $\epsilon$-neighborhoods centered at $a_1$ and $a_2$ do not intersect.

Comment: Why would that be a problem?

Comment: If you read the proof completely, you'll understand why epsilon is chosen this way.

Comment: @LostAce: Because if the terms of the sequence eventually settle within an $\epsilon$-neighborhood of $a_1$ **and** within an $\epsilon$-neighborhood of $a_2$, that would be a contradiction, because the neighborhoods do not intersect.

Comment: A contradiction to what?

Comment: A contradiction to the assumption that the sequence converges to both limits.

Comment: it might be a bit off-topic but the proof you are asking about does not prove that the convergent sequence has only one limit. It only proves that it does not have 2 limits. How to prove that it only has one limit?

Comment: assume that a=b (a-b=0)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you face is because of $\epsilon$ symbol. Suppose the two limits are $1$ and $2$. This means $a_{n}$ is near $1$ and also near $2$ for large $n$. If you get too close to $1$ then it is obvious that you are not close to $2$. The argument holds even if $1, 2$ are replaced by general numbers $a, b$ provided $a \neq b$.

But to demonstrate this fact (or to prove this fact) you need to quantify how close to one limit $a$ you want $a_{n}$ to be in order to get a bit far from $b$. The best approach is to consider a number which is equidistant from $a, b$. This is the mid point $c = (a + b)/2$. Consider them on real line (let $a$ be the smaller number):

$----a--------c--------b-----$

Clearly if you want your $a_{n}$ to be near $a$ and far from $b$ the only way is to keep the $a_{n}$ left of $c$ like the following

$----a----a_{n}----c--------b-----$

So the distance between $a_{n}$ and $a$ should be less than the distance between $a$ and $c$ i.e. $c - a = (b - a)/2$. This distance is what we quantify by $\epsilon$. Hence we need $\epsilon < (b - a)/2$.

Thinking in terms of real number line is such a great help to visualize the basic concepts related to inequalities and while learning calculus it is better to focus on this aspect rather than the boring $\epsilon, \delta$ stuff.

Answer (score 2):

If the sequence $(a_n)_{n \in \Bbb{N}} \in \Bbb{R}$ is convergent in $\Bbb{R}$, then there exists a number $a \in \Bbb{R}$ and **for every** $\varepsilon  > 0$ there exists a number $N$ such that $\left| a_n - a\right | < \varepsilon$ whenever $n > N$.

So suppose the sequence has **two** limits, $a_1$ and $a_2$. Since the sequence converges to $a_1$, we **can** find an $m > N$ such that $\left| a_m - a_1\right | < \frac{\varepsilon}{2}$. Remember, if the sequence converges, we can find a number so that the distance between the limit and the terms of the sequence is less than **any given positive number**, including $\frac{\varepsilon}{2}$.

Since we assumed the sequence also converged to $a_2$, we can do the same thing with that: we can find a $r > N$ such that $\left| a_r - a_2\right | < \frac{\varepsilon}{2}$.

Now, let $M = max (r,m)$. Then, for any $k > M$, both sequences will be within $\frac{\varepsilon}{2}$ of their limits.

So, now we can show that the limits are both arbitrarily close to one another:

$\left| a_1 - a_2\right | = \left| a_1 - a_k + a_k- a_2\right | \leq \left| a_1 - a_k \right |+ \left|a_k- a_2\right | < \frac{\varepsilon}{2} + \frac{\varepsilon}{2} = \varepsilon$.

The only trick we used was adding zero ($0 = -a_k + a_k$) and the triangle inequality ($|a + b| \leq |a| + |b|$) for all real numbers $a$ and $b$. So, the conclusion is that the distance between the two limits is smaller than any given arbitrary positive number. The only way this is possible is if they are the same number. So, that means the sequence has one limit which is therefore a unique limit.

Comment: So the number epsilon/2 is just an arbitrary number? Is that correct?

Comment: Right. You could use $\varepsilon$ divided by any integer and it'd still work. The reason they choose to divide by two is so that at the end, you end up with just $\varepsilon$, which looks nice.

Answer (score 1):

If a sequence $x_n$ in $\mathbb R$ converges to $a_1$ and $a_2$ with $a_1 \neq a_2$, then there would exist an $N$ with 
$$
 \lvert x_N - a_i \rvert < \epsilon
$$ for $i=1,2$ and $\epsilon = \frac{\lvert a_1 - a_2 \rvert} 2$. This cannot be true since the invervals $(a_i-\epsilon,a_i+\epsilon)$ are disjoint.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a rough and hopefully illuminating explanation: if a sequence $(u_n)$ converges to $a_1$, this means *any* neighbourhood $(a_1-\varepsilon, a_1+\varepsilon)$ of $a_1$ contains all terms $u_n$ of the sequence if $n$ is large enough, say $n\ge N_1$ ($N_1$ depends on $\varepsilon$, of course).

Similarly, if it converges to $a_2$, *any* neighbourhood of $a_2$ contains all $u_n$s if $n$ is large enough, say $n\ge N_2$ (not necessarily the same as $N1$).

Now, if $n $ is larger than $N_1$  and than $N_2$, all $u_n$s will be in both neigbourhoods $(a_1-\varepsilon, a_1+\varepsilon)$ **and**  $(a_2-\varepsilon, a_2+\varepsilon)$, which is plainly impossible if $\varepsilon$ was chosen so small  that the two neighbourhoods are disjoint — for instance if we *choose* $\;\varepsilon<\dfrac{\lvert a_1-a_2\rvert}2$

Comment: But why is it ε<∣a1−a2∣/2? Why not something larger? I am having trouble understanding it geometrically.

Comment: If it is larger, the wtwo neighbourhoods intersect. Make a sketch. Also, don't forget $\lvert a_1-a_2\rvert$ is the *distance* between $a1$  and $a_2$, and that, if we suppose, say, $a_1<a_2$, $\;a_1+\dfrac{\lvert a_1-a_2\rvert}2=\dfrac{a_1+a_2}2$, the mid-point of $a_1$ and $a_2$.

Comment: Why can't they intersect? Is it because if they had an intersection we wouldn't have a condition for which our assumption could be proved to be false which leads to a contradiction and thus a proof. If they intersected we would have one big 'neighbourhood' and thus all the terms in the sequence will be in that neighbourhood, so we wouldn't have any way of showing that a limit is unique. Correct?

Comment: Yes we choose an ‘interesting’ value of ε — or at least a value that is useful for what we aim at.